# sed command fail to understand with special chars

Tags: sed, sh

Can I know what exactly below command is doing

```
sed -e 's/^OR//.
```

I tried running different forms as below and understood it is replacing characters, but when I add `^` I can not understand the pattern

```
sed -e 's/OR//
sed -e 's/OR/re/
sed -e 's/OR/or/
```

Comment: See [Regex Tutorial: Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed -e 's/^OR//'` removes the first two characters of a line if they are `OR` since `^` starts matching from the start of a line.